# Why does the compiler say "undeclared identifier" for a variable I declared in the "if" statement just above?

Tags: c++, parameters, undeclared-identifier

Why is this throwing an error, undeclared identifier?

```
void IDcard::Prepare(CoatingDecorator *coating)
{
    if (select == 1) { IDcard *currentID = new Passport(); }
    else if (select == 2) { IDcard *currentID = new DriversLicence();   }

    AddPhoto();
    coating->Prepare(currentID);
    std::cout << "Total Cost: " << coating->totalCost; 
    DispenseID();
}
```

(specifically `currentID` parameter when calling `coating->Prepare(currentID)`).

As far as I can tell currentID is declared in the if statements.

Running this on MS VS2012, error code is C2065.

Comment: `currentID` only exists in the scopes it is declared in.

Comment: as in within the if statement?

Comment: In addition to what @juanchopanza said, where is `select` declared? I'm assuming it is a member/global?

Comment: @nonsensickle, it's declared in the class declarations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

currentID only exist in the if and the else, outside that its not declared, you can declare it before the IF and initialize inside the IF and Else.

Also as commented if select its not 1 or 2 it would not be initialized and can cause problems so make sure to initialize it.

```
void IDcard::Prepare(CoatingDecorator *coating)
{
IDcard *currentID;

if (select == 1) { currentID = new Passport(); }
else if (select == 2) { currentID = new DriversLicence();   }

AddPhoto();
coating->Prepare(currentID);
std::cout << "Total Cost: " << coating->totalCost; 
DispenseID();
}
```

Comment: Can you also please explain that `currentID` could remain uninitialized if the code is left as is? After that it will be +1.

Comment: awesome, thanks @LuisTellez, silly mistake on my part, but you probably saved me hours

Comment: @LuisTellez thanks for the updated answer, very informative as well as solving my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the currentID outside the if block to fix the error.

```
void IDcard::Prepare(CoatingDecorator *coating)
{
  IDcard *currentID = NULL;
  if (select == 1) { currentID = new Passport(); }
  else if (select == 2) { currentID = new DriversLicence();   }

  AddPhoto();
  coating->Prepare(currentID);
```

Comment: @LuisTellez was faster, but you are more correct. +1.

Comment: why = NULL, wouldn't it be = new IDcard(); ??

Comment: @user3001499 That implies that `IDcard()` is *constructable* which we don't know. Similarly, it is standard practice to initialise pointers to null although normally you wouldn't use NULL but 0 (i.e. `IDcard *currentID = 0` is the better choice).